# C# webbrowser applition,how to click hyper link inside TextArea

Tags: c#, hyperlink, browser, textarea

the html code may looks like

```
<html>
<body>
......
<textarea>
    <div>
        <a href="http://www.sohu.com">This is a hyper link </a>
    </div>
</textarea>
......
</body>
</html>
```

when i enum the links by

```
        foreach (HtmlElement item in ieBrowser.document.Links)
        {
            var innerText = item.InnerText;
            if ((string.IsNullOrEmpty(innerText)) || innerText.Length == 0) continue;
            if (innerText.Contains(task.ShopName))
            {
                item.ScrollIntoView(true);
                item.Focus();
                item.SetAttribute("selected", "true");
                item.SetAttribute("target", "_self");
                item.InvokeMember("Click");     
                break;
            }
        }
```

But,it seems that the webbrowser could not recognize the linkes inside textArea.
anybody who knows how to deal with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Content on textarea can be extracted by using [InnerHtml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelement.innerhtml.aspx) property. Then you can use [HTMLAgilityPack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack) to find a link and navigate it

```
HtmlElement textArea = webBrowser1.Document.All["textareaid"];
if (textArea != null)
{
    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
    doc.Load(textArea.InnerText);
    foreach(HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//a[@href"])
    {
       HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlAttribute att = link["href"];
       webBrowser1.Navigate(att.Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: thaks.i know it.but what i want is  `HtmlElement item.InvokeMember("Click");`  not `"href"` attribute.